# How can I implement SQL statement in Liquibase (insert multiple row)

Tags: sql, xml, database, liquibase

How can I implement the following SQL-Statement in Liquibase without sql-tag()?

"INSERT INTO PERSONS ( ID ) SELECT ID FROM CUSTOMERS"

Comment: You can implement your own change/refactoring, if that's what you need.  https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Change

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do

```
 <insert tableName="setting_value">
            <column name="col1" value="yourValue"/>
            <column name="col2" value="secondVal"/>
            <column name="col3" value="value3"/>
 </insert>
```

write multiple inser statements for more than 1 row

Comment: They don't know what rows they need to add- it would come from the table customers. This only works when you want to add a fixed number of rows and when you know the contents of those rows.

Comment: Yes you are right @NancyDeschênes. But mostly liquibase is used when you already know what data is to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without the sql tag.

Answer (score -1):

writing inserts like this;

```
<insert tableName="setting_value">
  <column name="col1" value="yourValue"/>
  <column name="col2" value="secondVal"/>
  <column name="col3" value="value3"/>
</insert>
```

multiple times inside a changeset tag works but not for all Databases especially Postgres, Maria DB, but it works for oracle db